# AWS Schema Conversion Tool on OSX- Driver Permissions - You don't have permission

Tags: java, macos, ojdbc, aws-sct

Just did my upgrade to OSX.
Using AWS Schema Conversion Tool 1.0.606 on OSX 10.13 with JRE 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17), JODBC driver ojdbc7.jar.

When try to add to Global Settings and point at the jodbc driver, get an error of "You don't have permissions to read or execute the specific object".  Same error for pointing at redshift driver.  Was not problem before the OSX upgrade.

SQLWorkbenchJ works fine with these drivers.

I have checked permissions on the .jar. I have opened the AWS SCT with sudo. And have reninstalled AWS SCT.

Not sure what broke on the OSX upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  Looks like you need to chmod +x ojdbc6.jar  and try again.